# regarding setting up Keras with Theano on GPU

Tags: theano, keras

I have been following the instruction for [setting up keras on GPU](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-keras-on-gpu) . This is what I did as suggested by method 3.

```
import theano
theano.config.device = 'gpu'
theano.config.floatX = 'float32'
```

However, I got the following error message

```
Using Theano backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 17, in 
theano.config.device = 'gpu'
File "/devl/geophys/dplearn/tensorflow/tf_0.12/lib/python3.4/site-     
packages/theano/configparser.py", line 338, in set

"Can't change the value of this config parameter "

Exception: Can't change the value of this config parameter after initialization!
```

Comment: you could try doing it when calling python:   THEANO_FLAGS=device=gpu,floatX=float32 python my_program.py

Comment: or you could make a .theanorc file in your `home` directory. Also please change 'gpu' to 'gpu0' or 'gpu1' and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in fact that when you are using `Theano` with `GPU` - while loading a package it is loading and compiling some non-pythonic functions (e.g. from `CUDA`). That's why changing this options causes exception - it's impossible to change this options in a precompiled code. In order to set this settings you need to change them in either `THEANO_FLAGS` in your path or your `.theanorc` file.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks. It seems to me that I could not find theanorc or theanorc.txt under /hom/   Does it mean I have to create it?  And in specific, which file should I create, .theanorc  or .theanorc.txt?

Comment: Which `os' do you use?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I am using linux,  I have created .theanorc under home directory. Looks like it removes the error message. However, it gave some GPU-related warning messages. I am asking it in another thread.

Comment: Hi Marcin, this the link to my another post related to this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816217/regarding-setting-up-gpu-for-theano