# regarding setting up GPU for theano

Tags: theano, theano-cuda

I configure the GPU under home/.theanorc  as follows

```
bash-4.1$ cat .theanorc
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0

[lib]
cnmem = 1
```

Running the program gives the following warning message, how to solve this problem?

```
python train.py                                                                        
Using Theano backend.                                                                                                     
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:                                                                          
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29                                                        

ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning regarding the cuda backend can be mitigated by following the steps in the provided link (https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29) 
This is only a warning and the code should run event if you don't fix it.

For the error you first need to make sure that nvcc compiler is installed and the path is setup correctly. assuming the installation is in the directory

**/usr/local/cuda-7.0**

you need to do the following

> export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin:$PATH

and

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH